# recaptcha very slow on linode server

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am using the following PHP to verify the google recaptcha:

function checkCapcha($response,$ip){

```
        try {


            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $data = ['secret'   => $secret,
                     'response' => $response,
                     'remoteip' => $ip];

            $options = [
                'http' => [
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query($data) 
                ]
            ];

            $context  = stream_context_create($options);
            $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            //return json_decode($result)->success;
             //echo $result;
            if(json_decode($result)->success){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }

}
```

It works perfectly from my home server, but when I use the same code on my linode it takes ages to come back with a result. The result is correct, but it takes about 3 mins.

Can someone please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you timed the operation? You might want to ask for your hosting provider's help if it involves slow network.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.  I am not sure that I understand you fully. The operation takes 2.8min of which just about all of it is Waiting time (TTFB). I also tested the server connection speed which is over 750Mbit/s. (speedtest.net), I also changed the 'www.google.com' part to the google IP address to check for DNS problems.   On my home server with _slow internet_ the waiting time is 400ms.

Answer (score 1):

I use Centos 7, I had the same problem.

First add a `www.google.com` `/etc/hosts` record, if this solves your problem, than turn off IPV6 on your server.

1. Append below lines in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```
2. To make the settings affective, execute :

   ```
   sysctl -p
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It takes 2000 ms on average to get the response back from Google API.

The thing is, if I use `curl`, it is that slow. If I switch back to plain `file_get_contents` function, it works much faster (i.e. normal timing).

Now when I thought the `curl` might be the culprit, it is not as when I target another HTTPS API it works flawlessly fast.

`curl` spends 99% of the time waiting for google API to respond back with a content, i.e. `[starttransfer_time] => 2.332313`

It's really weird.

So the solution would be to avoid `curl` in this use case and switch to `file_get_contents`, even though it is NOT the culprit!